# Delegation creates malfunction

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.settings').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('current');
    changeColor();
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('current');
});
```

Adds class "current" into the div.

```
function changeColor(){
$(document).on('mouseenter','.current',function() {
    $('.current').css("cursor","pointer");
    $('#this').css('background-color', $("div.current > div:nth-child(1)").attr('id'));
    $('#this1').css('background-color', $("div.current > div:nth-child(2)").attr('id'));
    $('#this2').css('background-color', $("div.current > div:nth-child(3)").attr('id'));
}).on('mouseleave', '.current', function() {
    $('#this').css('background-color', currentcolor);
    $('#this1').css('background-color', currentcolor1);
    $('#this2').css('background-color', currentcolor2);
})
};
```

Changes the color of several divs when the "current" div is hovered. The problem is when I try to change the first code into:

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.settings',function(){
    $(this).addClass('current');
}).on('mouseleave','.settings',function(){
    $(this).removeClass('current');
});
```

The second code does not function anymore.

Comment: How do you call `changeColor`?

Comment: This is just for a test man. Sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry I forgot. Updated.

Comment: So call `changeColor();` in the second version too?

Comment: @Hesus, your third code snippet has a mismatched event pair: it should be `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`, not `mouseover`/`mouseleave` (the appropriate pairing for `mouseover` would be `mouseout` but these events bubble up the DOM tree, which is not always desirable).

Comment: Changed it already, still doesn't work.

Comment: Your third code snippet doesn't contain `changeColor()`.